# How to check varchar variable if its Numeric or not in CASE When statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have complex query where i am having a varchar variable. I need to perform various operation on it based on the datatype of data i receive in that variable.

If varchar variable contains numeric value then i need to convert it to numeric datatype so i can perform > < operation on it.

It all works fine except below part

```
    Declare @testVal as varchar(50)='ok'
select CASE WHEN IsNUMERIC(@testVal)=1 THEN Cast(@testVal as numeric) ELSE 'n' End
```

Above query gives me error **"Error converting data type varchar to numeric."**

I can't use try_convert and advanced functions like that  as i am using older version of SQL.

Comment: *"I can't use try_convert and advanced functions like that as i am using older version of SQL."* - It would be useful to know which version of SQL Server you're using then

Comment: Using 2008 R2. And i have tried that answer with ISNUMERIC and its throwing error.

Comment: I have provided the sample query and error both in the question itself.

Comment: @Diado  If varchar variable contains numeric value then i need to convert it to numeric datatype so i can perform > < operation on it.

Comment: You're using ISNUMERIC as suggested in dup question but nature of problem is different.

Comment: Wait a second, you're returning a varchar if it's not numeric? You need to return the same type from all branches of the case statement

Comment: The problem is with the `'n'` part. ***THAT*** is what is causing the error. Change it to NULL or remove the else part altogether.

Comment: @Diado will that be a problem to return different Data Type?

Comment: Yes. As @SalmanA suggested, return `NULL` if it's not, otherwise SQL server will be unable to determine whether to treat the value as numeric or varchar.

Comment: `ISNUMERIC` is the most misleading function you'll ever encounter. It tells you that a string can be converted to **any** of the numeric data types, when surely what everyone cares about is whether it can be converted to a *specific* data type. `ISNUMERIC('£')` returns `1`. `CONVERT(numeric,'£')` returns the same error (it *can* be converted to `money`). It's usually better to pick which characters are legal and use some form of `like` expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work perfectly with sql_variant

```
select CASE WHEN IsNUMERIC(@testVal)=1 THEN Cast(@testVal as numeric) ELSE Cast(@testVal as sql_variant) End
```

Answer (score 2):

The `CASE` statement tries to consolidate the datatypes from all branches into one according to datatype precedence. In your example it is attempting to convert the varchar literal `'n'` to numeric hence the *error converting data type*. Remove the `ELSE` branch altogether:

```
CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(@testVal) = 1 THEN CAST(@testVal AS NUMERIC) END
```

Some examples:

```
SELECT val, CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(val) = 1 THEN CAST(val AS NUMERIC) END AS to_num
FROM (VALUES
    ('1'),
    (NULL),
    ('ok')
) AS v(val)
```

Result:

```
val  | to_num
-----+-------
1    | 1
NULL | NULL
ok   | NULL
```

You mentioned that you want to compare the numeric value using `<>`. NULL should have not problem with that, it simply won't match.

Comment: Will give this a try.

Comment: You are right. But unfortunately i need else part too. Can there be any work around for it?

Comment: Could you explain what exactly are you trying to do with `ELSE 'n' END`? You certainly cannot compare it with an INT.

Comment: I handled the else part the way you suggested and it worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: can i use sql_variant like below

else Cast(vMedexResult as sql_variant)

It seems working for me.